# Incorrectly defined object. Problem with importing an object from the library

Tags: python, pycharm, interactive-brokers

Here is the code for making order on IB with Python. This code works, but I get one error. In the end I try to make an order, but get an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
Getting the time from the server... 
  File "C:/Users/B/PycharmProject/1/api1.py", line 117, in <module>
    order1 = order.Order()
AttributeError: type object 'Order' has no attribute 'Order' 
IB error id -1 errorcode 2104 string Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm.nj
IB error id -1 errorcode 2104 string Market data farm connection is OK:usfuture
IB error id -1 errorcode 2104 string Market data farm connection is OK:cashfarm
IB error id -1 errorcode 2104 string Market data farm connection is OK:usfarm
IB error id -1 errorcode 2106 string HMDS data farm connection is OK:ushmds.us
IB error id -1 errorcode 2106 string HMDS data farm connection is OK:ilhmds
IB error id -1 errorcode 2106 string HMDS data farm connection is OK:njhmds
1544354853
```

I guess the problem is in the 5th and 6th rows. When I delete them, I get "name 'order' is not defined". I think I just define it incorrectly. Maybe someone faced with the similar problem/error?

```
from ibapi.wrapper import EWrapper
from ibapi.client import EClient
from threading import Thread
import queue
from ibapi.contract import Contract as contract
from ibapi.order import Order as order


class TestWrapper(EWrapper):
    """
    The wrapper deals with the action coming back from the IB gateway or TWS instance
    We override methods in EWrapper that will get called when this action happens, like currentTime
    """

    ## error handling code
    def init_error(self):
        error_queue=queue.Queue()
        self._my_errors = error_queue

    def get_error(self, timeout=5):
        if self.is_error():
            try:
                return self._my_errors.get(timeout=timeout)
            except queue.Empty:
                return None

        return None


    def is_error(self):
        an_error_if=not self._my_errors.empty()
        return an_error_if

    def error(self, id, errorCode, errorString):
        ## Overriden method
        errormsg = "IB error id %d errorcode %d string %s" % (id, errorCode, errorString)
        self._my_errors.put(errormsg)

    ## Time telling code
    def init_time(self):
        time_queue=queue.Queue()
        self._time_queue = time_queue

        return time_queue

    def currentTime(self, time_from_server):
        ## Overriden method
        self._time_queue.put(time_from_server)


class TestClient(EClient):
    """
    The client method
    We don't override native methods, but instead call them from our own wrappers
    """
    def __init__(self, wrapper):
        ## Set up with a wrapper inside
        EClient.__init__(self, wrapper)

    def speaking_clock(self):
        """
        Basic example to tell the time
        :return: unix time, as an int
        """

        print("Getting the time from the server... ")

        ## Make a place to store the time we're going to return
        ## This is a queue
        time_storage=self.wrapper.init_time()

        ## This is the native method in EClient, asks the server to send us the time please
        self.reqCurrentTime()

        ## Try and get a valid time
        MAX_WAIT_SECONDS = 10

        try:
            current_time = time_storage.get(timeout=MAX_WAIT_SECONDS)
        except queue.Empty:
            print("Exceeded maximum wait for wrapper to respond")
            current_time = None

        while self.wrapper.is_error():
            print(self.get_error())

        return current_time

class TestApp(TestWrapper, TestClient):
    def __init__(self, ipaddress, portid, clientid):
        TestWrapper.__init__(self)
        TestClient.__init__(self, wrapper=self)


        self.init_error()
        self.connect(ipaddress, portid, clientid)

        thread = Thread(target = self.run)
        thread.start()

        setattr(self, "_thread", thread)



if __name__ == '__main__':
    ##
    ## Check that the port is the same as on the Gateway
    ## ipaddress is 127.0.0.1 if one same machine, clientid is arbitrary

    app = TestApp("127.0.0.1", 4001, 10)

    current_time = app.speaking_clock()

    print(current_time)

    order1 = order.Order()
    order1.action = "BUY"
    order1.orderType = "MKT"
    order1.totalQuantity = 1



    contract1 = contract.Contract()
    contract1.symbol = "AMZN"
    contract1.secType = "FUT"
    contract1.exchange = "GLOBEX"
    contract1.currency = "USD"
    contract1.lastTradeDateOrContractMonth = "201903"

    app.placeOrder(6566, contract1, order1)

    app.disconnect()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is telling you that you have a class, `order`, which doesn't have an attribute `Order`. That is because of this line:

```
from ibapi.order import Order as order
```

where you import the class Order, but rename it to `order`. I don't know why you have done that, but don't. Either import the module:

```
from ibapi import order
```

and keep your existing instantiation code:

```
order1 = order.Order()
```

Or, import the class without renaming:

```
from ibapi.order import Order
```

and do

```
order1 = Order()
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is your import:

```
from ibapi.order import Order as order
```

You renamed the class `Order` to `order`.
Without trying it, the correct way should be:

```
order1 = order()
```